# Python- How to I turn an array into a set from an image?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set, tuples

Ok, so here's my code

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s, im = cam.read() # captures image
pixels=tuple(numpy.asarray(im))
pixel=set(pixels)
colour=set([0, 51, 14],[0, 51, 15],[0, 51, 16],etc
pixel.symmetric difference(colour)
```

I want to be able to make a Symmetric difference (Get all the similar numbers from two lists/sets) with the pixels of the image taken compared to a list of pixels I have stored.

I'm also aware my colour set method is rubbish/ probably wrong, but I'm doing one thing at a time.

Anyway, I keep trying to convert the pixel/pixels to a list or a set, but this keeps coming up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Listo.py", line 9, in <module>
    pixel=set(pixels)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

So like, yeah. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `asarray` seems superfluous, it already is a numpy array. Did you try first converting it into a [Python list using `tolist()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)? It will still be a list of lists (rows), so you should probably reshape it first to have only 1 row.

Comment: Have you considered sticking with numpy arrays rather than sets, and using numpy's vectorized [array set operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.set.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example transcript from the interpreter.

```
>>> import cv2
>>> import numpy as np
```

First we read in the image. I use a static image, but `VideoCapture` will return the same data structure. It's already a `numpy.ndarray`.

```
>>> img = cv2.imread("test1.png")
>>> type(img)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> img.shape
(76, 121, 3)
```

We first reshape the image, so that it's a single row of BGR pixels.

```
>>> img = img.reshape(1,-1,3)
>>> img.shape
(1, 9196, 3)
```

Then we convert the `ndarray` to a Python list using the [`tolist()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method. We can see that it's two nested lists, the top level list containing the rows, and second level containing columns (i.e. pixels).

```
>>> img_list = img.tolist()
>>> len(img_list)
1
>>> len(img_list[0])
9196
```

To be able to hash the pixels, we need to convert them into tuples. The Python `map` function works well for this. We already have all the pixels in the single row, so we use that.

```
>>> img_tuples = map(tuple, img_list[0])
>>> len(img_tuples)
9196
```

Now we can create a set of pixels.

```
>>> img_set = set(img_tuples)
>>> len(img_set)
5981
```

Finally, you can create your target colour set, again using tuples to represent the BGR triplets.

```
>>> colour=set([(0, 51, 14),(0, 51, 15),(0, 51, 16)])
>>> colour
set([(0, 51, 16), (0, 51, 15), (0, 51, 14)])
```

And find the symmetric difference of the two.

```
>>> img_diff = img_set.symmetric_difference(colour)
>>> len(img_diff)
5984
```